# Uno went in washer and when I shake I hear something shaking around. What do I hear?

Tags: arduino-uno

My friends Uno went in washer. I gave it a week to dry and when i plug it in, it works. But when I shake I hear something shaking around inside it. What do I hear shaking around?

Comment: There is no "inside" to have something shaking around, other than maybe the spaces in the DIP socket. Remove the DIP chip and see if there's something stuck in there.

Comment: Unless of course you have it in some form of case, in which case take it out of the case and case the joint. (English is a *fun* language, isn't it? ;) )

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion. (Yes English is.)

Comment: Just checked the socket. Nothing there. I shook it with the processor removed but I still hear something.

Comment: Maybe it’s the crystal? Idk.

Comment: Maybe it's in the power jack socket.

Comment: Possibly. At least it works.

Comment: My guess would be the pushy-part of the reset button. Try putting your finger on different part, then shake, and see if the sound is still there. I don't think it's something to worry about. As for the washing machine part; I wouldn't use that Arduino on something really important. Though it's probably fine.

Comment: it is probably the bits in the bit bucket ... lol

Comment: But the real question is does the magic smoke come out when you plug it in and turn it on.

Comment: Did you examine the board carefully no electronic part is broken or came out of PCB?

Comment: your question is not really about an arduino ... the same question could apply to a box of matches

Answer (score 0):

It could be the USB port, barrel jack port, or most likely the pin header. The pin headers are a plastic shell with a two-point prong thing that goes in it. the pin could have desoldered when in the washer. check the pin headers. It might also be the inside of capacitors but that is highly unlikely.